# ATMEGA8-16PU as a frequency counter with I2C output with frequency range from 0.05 Hz to 7.5 MHz

Tags: adc, atmega

Original question:

I would like to know if there are already existing projects and programming that is available to use ATMEGA8-16PU as a frequency counter with I2C output with frequency range from 0.05 Hz to 7.5 MHz.
If you know of any, please share the information.

Reason for the question:

I was searching for a frequency counter chip or circuit that has I2C capability and range of measurement from around 10 Hz to 7 MHz.
I found online a chip, called "UFDC-1". https://www.sensorsportal.com/HTML/E-SHOP/PRODUCTS_4/UFDC_1.htm
I bought 4 of them. Once I got it, chips had original marking scraped away with a hand-made label "UFDC-1" placed on top. Chip came with it's own datasheet and application notes. On the plastic tubing that it came with there was an original label, ATMEGA8-16PU-ND (possibly from Digi-Key), led me to believe that the original marking of the chip is indeed ATMEGA8. I then compared pinouts of both chips and they are identical.
Now, I do not have a problem purchasing a programmed chip, but I do have a problem with not being told what the original chip is, I have a right to know and to choose if I want that to be in my circuit. I would like it to be more upfront approach and not attempt to hide the original away from the view.

I thank you for the comments and answers, it fully makes sense now what I am working with. Again, I do not claim to know better, and in no way I will be able to take a blank ATMEGA8 chip and program it to perform the functions of UFDC-1 at this time. I will ask the author to be more upfront with myself and others in the future.

Comment: Very unlikely. Also, you're essentially asking for a ready-made design, and that's not a question within the scope requirements, imho.

Comment: You can, however, ask a better question! For example, I'm sure you have an approach already, and a reason why you'd use exactly this MCU (hint: bad choice, too slow and doesn't have the right peripherals built in to make your life easy, also unnecesarily expensive), and, most importantly, an application for that frequency counter – it's an unusually large range of input frequencies, so there's a lot of specific design tradeoffs to be made, here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: The ATMEGA8-16PU is both fast enough (16 MHz) and has the necessary peripherals (TWI, timers) for this application. It's just a SMOP (simple matter of programming)! Obviously, the OP needs to add a lot more information about system requirements, such as accuracy and update rate.

Comment: also, hm, DIP and 7.5 MHz does *not* pose a problem in itself. New design in 2020, and a DIP: this screams like "I want to breadboard this", and a frequency counter for 7.5 MHz on breadboard sounds like a lot of missed pulses/glitches/fun for the whole lab.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: What are you talking about? The TWI isn't used for the frequency measurement at all; it's just for the I2C communication to the host. The timers are used for the frequency/period measurement.

Comment: err, sorry, my confusion. You're right, I was confusing TWI with timer unit, and it is also true that if you implement a frequency counter, the high frequency end wouldn't be a problem (aside from requiring you to prescale for the lower frequencies, reducing your dynamic range, which anything with a 32 bit counter would solve, but oh well, can adapt around that).

Comment: still, a 32 bit counter would be *highly* desirable here, I'd say.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: You can extend a hardware counter to any number of bits by simply counting the overflow events in software.

Comment: @DaveTweed but I thought the Atmega8 didn't do nested interrupts?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Why would nesting be required? There's no problem with processing interrupts sequentially.

Comment: sorry, wasn't precise enough: I thought triggering an ISR automatically disables all interrupts, so you'd lose them? (You'll notice I haven't used an atmega in ~13 years)

Comment: Yes, interrupts are disabled, but that doesn't mean that they are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for a complete design, which you aren't going to get here. But yes, the chip you have should be quite capable of doing what you want. It has both hardware timers and a hardware TWI (I2C) peripheral, and the timers are fast enough (16 MHz) to cover the frequency range you're interested in.

Here are some general notes on the approach I'd take.

Set up one of the counters as a timebase, driven by the CPU clock if it's accurate enough, or by an external clock. Extend the range of this timebase if necessary by counting its overflow events in software.

To cover such a wide frequency range, you're going to want to use two different modes of operation. For high frequencies, feed the unknown clock into another hardware timer, and read that counter's value at time intervals determined by the timebase. The frequency of the input is simply the counter value (i.e., the difference between two readings) divided by the time interval.

For low frequencies, you'll want to switch to a period measurement. Use the unknown clock as an interrupt trigger, and read the value of the timebase on each interrupt. The period of the input is simply the difference between two readings, multiplied by the timebase clock period. You can derive the frequency using simple math.